# Jquery Disable Button Data to be changed on Submission

Tags: jquery, button

I have a jquery button which is disabled on submission, if any errors it enables. I want the button data to be changed on submission and if any errors change back to the data as previous.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".create-user", function (e) {
          $(this).html('Please Wait...');
          $(".create-user").attr("disabled", true);
        // submit form
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: $("#projectsId").serialize(),
            url: $("#projectsId").attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){ 
                if(data.status){
                    $.pjax.reload({container:"#projectsGrid"});
                    $('#modal').modal("hide");
                }else{
                    $('#projectsId').yiiActiveForm('updateMessages', data.errors, true);

                     $(".create-user").attr("disabled", false);
                     $(this).html('Create');
                }
            }
        });
```

It changes to "**please wait"** when I submit, but when there are errors it doesn't change back to **"Create"**. 
Few answers will be helpful.. Thanks :-)

Comment: Try  $(this).val("Create");

Comment: use val() or text() instead of html(). Also make sure the response hits the error block

Comment: Add `error:function(data)` to your `ajax` and make its text back to normal again..

Answer (score 0):

Just add the error function in your ajax use `val()` or `text()` instead of html

```
         if(data.status){
                    $.pjax.reload({container:"#projectsGrid"});
                    $('#modal').modal("hide");
                }else{
                    $('#projectsId').yiiActiveForm('updateMessages', data.errors, true);

                     $(".create-user").attr("disabled", '');
                     $(this).text('Create');
                     $(this).val('Create');
                }
```

Comment: No there are no changes.. Its the same when I click Create the text changes to Please wait. Does'nt Change back to create

Comment: did u check whether it comes to else condition ? @MohanPrasad

Comment: Yes It does Come... Because if there are validation errors the button is enabled....

Comment: still button seems to be disabled ?. if ur are facing the same issue again better use this `$('.create-user').prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: Nope.. If validation errors present button is enabled ... But the text from **Please Wait** has to be changed to **Create** again. On click the button text changes to **please wait...**. If there are no errors.. No issues, the page is redirected so No issues... if there are errors it will remain in the same page .. so i want the text changed back to **create** from the **please wait..**

Comment: so please make ensure that  you need to write the condition in else ? -may i know what type of error in ajax returns ?

Comment: so wat it will return in ajax success if it has error ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try `$('.create-user').prop("disabled", false);` to remove disabled property.

Answer (score 0):

you can intercept the error like you're doing for success with the command error in your ajax call like this :

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: $("#projectsId").serialize(),
            url: $("#projectsId").attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',

            error: function() { .... },
            success: function(data){ 
                if(data.status){
                    $.pjax.reload({container:"#projectsGrid"});
                    $('#modal').modal("hide");
                }else{
                    $('#projectsId').yiiActiveForm('updateMessages', data.errors, true);

                     $(".create-user").attr("disabled", false);
                     $(this).html('Create');
                }
            }
        });
```